# React Native loading Delight VR video player

Tags: react-native, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality, delightvr

I'm migrating a Cordova application to React-Native.

We have a VR Player on the app, for use with VR headsets (Google Cardboard, Samsung Gear, etc), but that also can be played as a regular 360 2D video.
[Delight VR](https://delight-vr.com/) provides everything we need, with built-in controls, and it works very nicely on Cordova.

While migrating to React-Native we couldn't find any similar native player for it, the closest one is [ViroMedia](https://viromedia.com/viroreact), however, it doesn't provide any built-in controls, doesn't support other projections than 360 (our videos can come in different projection, i.e: 180 LR, 360 UD, etc).

The support team at Delight VR replied us confirming that we could use a React Native Webview for loading their player.
It's not the ideal solution, but it is the best we could find.

Then, I'm trying to implement it using react-native-webview, but for now I couldn't have any success.

`The video source is stored in an S3 bucket and it is public accessible`

I've tried loading a local webpage

```
    <WebView style={styles.container}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{ html: mypage }}
    />
```

Didn't work, got a few messages related to origin and the player keeps loading forever. 
After a bit of tests I found out that delight vr requires a web server running, the origin can't be a file, not sure if that was the reason it was failing.
Anyway, I had set up a web server, a public URL, and tested it on the browser and it worked nicely.
So I've changed my code to point to this URL

```
    <WebView style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: 'https://myurl.com/' }}
    />
```

Now, when I try to play the video, I get the message

> Content Issue
>
> No playable video source found

When I go to the url context in the Safari to debug the issue, I see that the requests to the video don't return an error, however if I go to the preview tab I see the messsage `An error occurred trying to load the resource`

I have also tried different options
i.e: `mixedContentMode='always' allowFileAccess={true} allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}`

Any idea of what might be causing this issue?
If you know any other alternatives for loading VR (and regular) videos on React-Native with similar Delight VR features, it is also an option to switch to it.

Comment: have you looked into this package [react-native-360](https://github.com/tiero/react-native-360) ??

Comment: @Ron Yes, but it looks immature, not updated often, and no Android support (it links to another package for Android, which has zero documentation)